# SPA Cookie based authentication in whitelabeled environment

Tags: authentication, jwt, single-page-application, httpcookie

As we all know by know storing JWT tokens (or any other auth token) in local storage is not a good idea (see: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04)

I am now building a SPA that will be used in a whitelabel setup by default.
Meaning that this SPA will be served from acme.com, example.com, bla.com etc.

I however cannot whitelabel our API (that issues the Auth cookies with a JWT inside) due to CORS.

How would I be able to approach this?

Many thanks in advance;